# It always fails when to delete or drop table using sqlalchemy on postgresql

Tags: python, postgresql, sqlalchemy

One simple function is built to execute sql

```
from sqlalchemy.engine.url import URL
POOL_RECYCLE = 7200
POOL_SIZE = 10
MAX_OVERFLOW = 20
POOL_TIMEOUT = 30

class DatabaseConnect(object):
    def __init__(self, dict_db):
        self.__config = dict_db
        self.Engine = create_engine(URL(**self.__config),
                                    pool_size=POOL_SIZE,
                                    max_overflow=MAX_OVERFLOW,
                                    pool_timeout=POOL_TIMEOUT,
                                    pool_recycle=POOL_RECYCLE)
    def db_connect(self):
        return self.Engine.connect()
```

One dict is used to include info to connect database.

```
DICT_DB_DW_PG_BI = {
    'drivername': 'postgres',
    'host': 'xxx',
    'port': '5432',
    'database': 'alpha',
    'username': 'xx',
    'password': 'xxx'}
```

When I run the sql, I use the function as belows:

```
for i_sql in sql_input.split(';'):
    engine = self.db_dw_pg_bi.Engine
    engine.execute(sqlalchemy.text(i_sql))
```

When I use the method above to run the sql as below, no error is shown, but when I check the database, I found no changes on the database.

```
delete from  test.lxy_norm_user;
drop table if exists test.lxy_norm_user;
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems to be the issue on `autocommit`.
I modify the part-3 method as below and it works.
`self.db_dw_pg_bi.Engine.execute(sqlalchemy.text(i_sql).execution_options(autocommit=True))`,